# Why isn't this code leaking?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am new to development and can not figure this out:

```
 for(NSString *collectionName in jsonObjects)
  {
    NSDictionary *collection = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    collection = [jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName];
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[collection valueForKey:@"items"]];
    NSNumber *lastAccess = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

    lastAccess = [collection valueForKey:@"lastAccess"];

    [items release];
  }
```

I don't understand why it is, that when I DO release either *lastAccess* or *collection*, the program crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error..., but if I DONT release *items* I get a leak. Can anyone please shed light on this. I thought that if you used alloc, then you owned the reference and must therefore release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(NSString *collectionName in jsonObjects)
{
  NSDictionary *collection = [[NSDictionary alloc] init]; // Allocation 
  collection = [jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName]; // overwriting above, LEAKS
  NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[collection valueForKey:@"items"]]; // Allocation
  NSNumber *lastAccess = [[NSNumber alloc] init]; // Allocation
  lastAccess = [collection valueForKey:@"lastAccess"]; // overwriting above, LEAKs
  [items release];
}
```

calls that don't contain 'alloc' or 'new' return references to object that are 'autoreleased' which means they are not owned by you, releasing them will cause a crash. You can use them but only in the scope of the function that you are in, if you need them for later use you will need to call `retain` on them. So when calling accessor functions you only need to declare the variables that you need and not create new objects.

`alloc` creates a new object, in the case of `collection` you are creating an empty `NSDictionary`, but you promptly overwrite the reference to that new object with the autoreleased reference you get from `valueForKey:` this will create a leak. As the originally created object won't get released.

probably should look like this

```
for(NSString *collectionName in jsonObjects)
{
  NSDictionary *collection = [jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName];
  NSArray *items = [collection valueForKey:@"items"];
  NSNumber *lastAccess = [collection valueForKey:@"lastAccess"];
}
```

I realize that with the capability of having questions like this answered by a willing crowd reading the manuals has become just a chore but if you want to progress you should have a look, most of the apple documentation is exceptionally well written as these things go. The [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) will resolve a lot of questions.

Comment: Thanks Harald, I have looked at the memory management guide, but misunderstood I guess :( I do understand though what you are saying about overwriting my initial alloc/init, however I do have a question regarding the functional difference then between NSDictionary *collection = [jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName]; and NSDictionary *collection = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName]]; i.e. are these two declarations functionally equivalent, the documentation does not make it clear?

Comment: Yes and no, the are the same that neither of the two call returns a reference to something that you own (look neither of them contain 'alloc' or 'new' or 'copy', but the first creates a new dictionary and initialises it with the value of the given dictionary (it is called a 'convenience constructor'), the second just returns a the corresponding dictionary. 

[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:...] is _different_ than [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:...] the second _does_ create an object that you own

Comment: Thanks Harald, you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of problems with that code.  Ignoring, for the moment, that the Foundation caches certain commonly used values.

This pattern makes no sense:

```
NSDictionary *collection = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
collection = [jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName];
```

The first line creates an (empty) instance of NSDictionary and the second line promptly overwrites the reference to it.  Both a leak and entirely pointless; there is no need for the assignment/allocation on the first line.   Same goes for `lastAccess` later.

Since the second line is returning an un-owned reference, attempting to `release` it will cause a crash.

Note that **if there is a crash, there will be a backtrace**.   This question is straightforward enough that it isn't needed, but always look to the backtrace for clues.

Note that you won't actually see a leak of either the `NSNumber` or `NSDictionary` instances because the Foundation happens to have singletons of those.  In the NSNumber case it just doesn't make sense.  Empty dictionaries, though, are used pretty often and having a singleton saves memory.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me bbum, I'm not quite sure what singletons are but I'll check out the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

In that code, you're just reassigning the `lastAccess` pointer, which leaves the `alloc`ed `NSNumber` leaked. You need to actually set the value for the `NSNumber` object pointed to by `lastAccess`.

EDIT:

I had placed some example code, but I'm taking it out, since I realize now that the code sample above has too many issues. Take a look at the documentation for `NSDictionary`. With `collection`, you're creating an object, and then leaking it by reassigning its pointer to something else. Once you get those issues ironed out, I recommend updating the question with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Following @bbum above, i'd write your code like this:

```
for(NSString *collectionName in jsonObjects)
{
NSDictionary *collection = [jsonObjects valueForKey:collectionName];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[collection valueForKey:@"items"]];
NSNumber * lastAccess = [collection valueForKey:@"lastAccess"];
}
```

All variables in this case will be autoreleased, so you don't need to do release them manually.